# Google Analytics real-time data into a 'top' like CLI

Tags: monitoring, command-line-interface, web, google-analytics

Does anyone know of a project or set of scripts that attempts to bring Google Analytics data to the command line? What I dream about is a "top" like application that lets me monitor Google Analytics real-time data without a web browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not. The only API for accessing that data is in limited beta (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GoAccess](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/) tool is not *'Google Analytics'* based, 
but it is an open source real-time web log analyzer and interactive viewer that runs in a terminal in CLI like 'top' and handles a lot of web log formats.

[image: GoAccess screenshot]

Comment: That is really cool and I will try it on my testing server. However, I am interested in something I can run on my "local" machine without taking any server resources. That's why I was thinking of an implementation of the Google Analytics Real-time Panel just in CLI form.

Comment: you can run it from your local machine: `ssh root@server 'cat /var/log/apache2/access.log' | goaccess -a --no-progress`